# Use variable instead of fixed search term in PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am using the following to replace / shorten a string which works fine so far. 
How can I use a variable here (e.g. $myVar) instead of the hard-coded search term (mySearchTerm) ?

```
preg_match('/mySearchTerm\:\s*([^\_]+)/', $myString, $out);
```

Comment: Think about string concatenation, do not forget to use `preg_quote()`

Comment: @HamZa: Thanks, can you explain how I need to use this to achieve the above ?

Comment: Telling a newbie to read the manual without pointing him to anything is one of the least helpful things ever...

Comment: @OneOfOne How hard is it to use your favorite search engine `php preg_quote` or add `preg_quote` to `http://php.net/` and hit `enter`? If we were talking about the [pcre docs](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) that would be another story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using concatenation and [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) :

```
$term = 'mySearchTerm';
preg_match('/' . preg_quote($term, '/') . ':\s*([^_]+)/', $myString, $out);
```

Comment: Thanks so much - this is what I was looking for ! Will accept as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

If you do the below, the first bit can be any text you want. You must use any characters followed by the `:`

```
preg_match('/([^:]+):\s*([^_]+)/', $myString, $out);
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this doesnt help me as I need to check for the search term.

Comment: You would have it in your $out array